# ORDER BY date in MySQL, receiving error

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-order-by

I have a SQL table with a date value (name is date and type is datetime).
I need to order my output by date, but I recive a error message:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ORDER BY date ASC' at line 1

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Posts1 LIMIT 10 ORDER BY date ASC";
```

Comment: You have a column named "date" in the table Posts1?

Comment: Might be worth adding MySQL tag to this question, as it's not apparent from the title that it's specifically about MySQL.  EDIT: thanks for fixing up the tags.

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes, now it's renamed to postDate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put 'LIMIT' at the end like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Posts1 ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Although, I don't think single quotes around 'date' will help because then it is treated as a string literal and not the column name.

Comment: Ohh it should be backticks.

Comment: Yes, or could be changed to `Posts1.date`. I think OP said they changed the name of the column anyways, but it's good to note that the single quotes will not work in any case.

Comment: or it could just be left as date

Comment: @Strawberry yes, but isn't convention to do otherwise, so as to avoid confusion? I know it *could* be date, but certainly something like `postDate` would be more relevant.

Comment: Yes it is always better to have table.column structure. We can use it like this as well Posts1.`date`.

Comment: @McAdam331 That's a completely different point - and, as it happens, one with which I tend to agree. Keywords, reserved or otherwise, can cause confusion when used as table/column identifiers, and so probably best avoided - but that's not why the OP's query failed.

Comment: Thank you, your help was wery helpful

Comment: It's not the backticks or something like that... It was the LIMIT, but thanks!